# Setting CoreBluetooth peripheral.delegate in a class

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm attempting to discover services etc from a CoreBluetooth peripheral, but I've run into an issue because `peripheral.delegate = self` (as I've seen in every tutorial) is attempting to set the peripheral.delegate to the parent BluetoothHandler object.

My relevant code is:

```swift
class BluetoothHandler: NSObject, ObservableObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
  func centralManager (_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral {
    peripheral.delegate = self // Cannot assign value of type BluetoothHandler to CBPeripheralDelegate?
    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: ` (as I've seen in every tutorial)` which object is supposed to be the CBPeripheralDelegate? See its methods to see?

Comment: Normally it's done in the ViewController (since they were UIKit tutorials), but this tutorial https://www.novelbits.io/intro-ble-mobile-development-ios-part-2/ uses the same BluetoothHandler setup (but anything past setting up the scan/connection itself is paywall locked)

Comment: The error is telling you that `self` aka an instance of `BluetoothHandler` doesn't conform to `CBPeripheralDelegate`. If you want that object to be your delegate that make your class conform to that protocol and implement the required functions.

Comment: Usually we put `self`, or the object creating it as the delegate. But that's not necessary the case. It's all about who will handle the delegate methods, who needs them, and who might responds to them (for instance, in a UITableViewDatasSource, it's the delegate pattern, and the tableView is asking its source for the number of rows, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `BluetoothHandler` does not conform to the right delegate protocol, which is `CBPeripheralDelegate` instead of or in addition to `CBCentralManagerDelegate`.

Also note that you should typically keep hold of your connected peripheral, e.g. like this:

```
class BluetoothHandler: NSObject, ObservableObject, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    
    var connectedPeripheral: CBPeripheral?
    
    func centralManager (_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        
        connectedPeripheral = peripheral
        
        connectedPeripheral?.delegate = self
        
        connectedPeripheral?.discoverServices(nil)
    }
    
}
```